# gdal_calc.py does not work under sbt

Tags: python, scala, sbt, gdal

I run a command line gdal_calc.py in a scala script. I run this script with 'sbt run' on my terminal. I got this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/gdal_calc.py", line 329, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/bin/gdal_calc.py", line 326, in main
    doit(opts, args)
  File "/usr/local/bin/gdal_calc.py", line 282, in doit
    myResult = ((1*(myNDVs==0))*myResult) + (myOutNDV*myNDVs)
TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index
```

Running the command gdal_calc.py in my terminal works well.
Running the exact same command line directly in my terminal doesn't work. The environment is the same : the gdal library used is the same

The command line runned is the following :

```
gdal_calc.py --outfile=outfile.tiff -A infile.tiff --overwrite --calc="3*(A==2)"
```

Can someone explain it ? Thanks !

Comment: Can't explain it, but I'm experiencing the same issue when calling gdal_calc.py in a subprocess.call in Python. I'll probably end up doing the same workaround as you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to my problem :
I'm writing my gdal_calc.py command line into a shell script and then executing it thought shell. 
It's not resolving the problem but bypassing ;)

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with Scala, but like Samuel I experienced the problem calling gdal_calc.py from a Python script with 'subprocess.call()'.

I suspect there must be some issue when the arguments get handed over to 'gdal_calc.py' by 'subprocess.call()'.

The solution was to use the 'subprocess.call' argument 'shell = True', executing the call as a single string through the shell:

```
subprocess.call('gdal_calc.py --outfile=outfile.tiff -A rasterA.tiff
                -B rasterB.tiff --calc="A+B"', shell = True)
```

Maybe 'sbt run' in Scala has a similar option?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a shell script, you can always launch it from a python script with something like this:

```
# import section
import os

# Manual input
a_source = "aaa.tif"
b_source = "bbb.tif"
output = "out.tif"
calc = '"(A**B)*(B==1)"'

# The command itself
gdal_calc = 'python {Path root}/Lib/site-packages/osgeo/scripts/gdal_calc.py ' \
            '-A {0} ' \
            '-B {1} ' \
            '--outfile={2} ' \
            '--calc={3} ' \
            '--type=Float32 ' \
            '--overwrite'.format(a_source, b_source, output, calc)

# Launch the command
os.system(gdal_calc)
```

I found this much easier and clearer.